# How to retain variable values when using quit()?

Tags: karate

I understand using quit() isn't recommended for many scenarios and I tried not to use it but I am forced to, to make it simple.

Scenario: Accessing a web app that forces user to sign in through Azure OIDC. Once the user signs in, I need to do a few things, sign out and then sign back in as a different user. Problem is, even though I run all my tests in incognito browser mode (to get around cache issues), when I attempt to login with the second user, it retains the first user's info and that is not something we want.

I got around that by using quit() after the first user and then launching a new instance of the browser as the second user.

However, the problem I was found was, the variables I had declared to store important info is wiped after using the quit().

Is there a way to retain variable values after using quit()?

Steps:

```
        Given driver 'www.test.com'
        * driver.maximize()
        * call read('login.feature@login') 
        * def variable = (driver.text('title')).trim()
        * quit()
        Given driver 'www.test.com'
        * driver.maximum()
        * call read('login.feature@login') {user2: '#(user2)'}
        * karate.log(variable)
```

The log for "variable" comes up blank, i.e it loses the value that was fed into it prior to the quit().

Please advise if there is a better way to handle the user switch without using the quit() or a way to retain variable values after using quit() (preferable route).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: as far as I know `variable` should not be affected. so it is quite likely that your `login.feature` is doing something that overwrites it. there is only one way to find out if we need to fix it - and you know the drill ...

Comment: It seems because my called method was calling *another* method and then back to my primary script, by the time I got to my primary script, that variable was lost. It shouldn't have been overwritten because I didn't have that variable defined elsewhere. Was not aware this could happen as I am using similar architecture elsewhere. Thanks for the help @PeterThomas.

Comment: it would be nice to not have to continue to wonder if karate has any bugs, but thanks for the update ;)